# Quarkus MicroProfile JWT auth via JWKS

Tags: jwt, quarkus, microprofile, jose4j

I'm attempting to use a JWKS endpoint to supply a public key for verifying a JWT signature. In my `application.properties`, I've set the following:

```
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location = http://localhost:1080/jwks
```

It appears that this is indeed being used:

```
2019-08-17 18:02:28,593 DEBUG [io.sma.jwt.con.JWTAuthContextInfoProvider] (executor-thread-1) init, mpJwtPublicKey=NONE, mpJwtIssuer=NONE, mpJwtLocation=http://localhost:1080/jwks
2019-08-17 18:02:28,599 DEBUG [io.sma.jwt.aut.AbstractBearerTokenExtractor] (executor-thread-1) tokenHeaderName = Authorization
2019-08-17 18:02:28,643 DEBUG [io.qua.sma.jwt.run.aut.JwtIdentityManager] (executor-thread-1) verify, id=null, credential=io.quarkus.smallrye.jwt.runtime.auth.JWTCredential@780ca7ed
2019-08-17 18:02:28,719 DEBUG [io.sma.jwt.aut.pri.KeyLocationResolver] (executor-thread-1) Trying location as JWK(S)...
```

When attempting a request to an endpoint in this app, it crashes with:

```
2019-08-17 18:02:29,048 WARN  [io.sma.jwt.aut.pri.DefaultJWTTokenParser] (executor-thread-1) Token is invalid: JWT (claims->{"identityType":"user","authorities":[],"accountId":"0812081208","userId":"ybx8912jq59","iat":1566086374,"exp":1566089974}) rejected due to invalid claims. Additional details: [[17] Unexpected exception thrown from validator org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.IssValidator: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.IssValidator.expectedValue(IssValidator.java:72); org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.IssValidator.validate(IssValidator.java:59); ...omitted...]
2019-08-17 18:02:29,050 DEBUG [io.qua.sma.jwt.run.aut.JwtIdentityManager] (executor-thread-1) failed, id=null, credential=io.quarkus.smallrye.jwt.runtime.auth.JWTCredential@780ca7ed: org.wildfly.security.auth.server.RealmUnavailableException: Failed to verify token
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.jwt.runtime.auth.MpJwtValidator.validateClaimsSet(MpJwtValidator.java:44)
```

The best I can understand from this stack trace, `id=null` might be a problem? I have nothing else to really go on here as I can confirm that this JWT is valid as I'm the one who generated it, and it can be validated via other apps.

I do not have access to add other fields/values to this JWT as I don't own the auth system. Is there any way I can get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The NPE from `IssValidator` suggests you are probably running into this https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/issues/135/issvalidator-throws-nullpointerexception which means your token needs an issuer `iss` claim or the JWT consumer needs to not be set to require an `iss` claim via not using any of the `setExpectedIssuer[s]` methods on the builder.

Comment: also never use plain http for the JWKS endpoint in real usage

Comment: Nope, this is local dev mode only (that endpoint returns a mock JSON obj). Since this is quarkus, the expected issuers are set by an application property, not a builder. I'm having trouble understanding how to use a builder instead.